# Refreshing a DIV containing PHP on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am building a calendar and am almost complete. The final thing to do is allow the user to select a date and have the calendar `div` refresh starting from the date chosen on a button submit. So far I have done this in my `calendar.php` file:

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" id="arrivaldate" style="width:80px; margin-top:20px;" /></div>
<input type="submit" id="go" value="GO" />
```

and here are the scripts for that:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
});
</script>
<script>
$('#go').click( function() {
    var date = $('.datepicker');
    var datastring = {date:date};
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "classes/create_cal.php",
        data: datastring,
        cache:false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('.calendar').load('classes/create_cal.php');
        },
        error: function(){
              alert('Error Adding Unit');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

here is part of the code from `classes/create_cal.php`. It receives the `GET` data and sets the date:

```
//get date from $_GET
    $date = (isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : date("Y-m-d"));
    $date_arr = explode("-",$date);
    $year = $date_arr[0];
    $month = $date_arr[1];
    $day = $date_arr[2];
```

Right now I am getting the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.10.2.js:7499
add                                    jquery-1.10.2.js:7499
buildParams                            jquery-1.10.2.js:7551
buildParams                            jquery-1.10.2.js:7546
buildParams                            jquery-1.10.2.js:7546
buildParams                            jquery-1.10.2.js:7546
jQuery.param                           jquery-1.10.2.js:7519
jQuery.extend.ajax                     jquery-1.10.2.js:8021
(anonymous function)                   calendar.php:115
jQuery.event.dispatch                  jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handle                        jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
```

---

I feel as if, void of errors, this is still the wrong approach to this. I had posted a similar question before and ended up finding my own answer, the same solution I am following now. I just know there must be a better way to do this. I know it's very simple in Visual Studio (with the UpdatePanel) I just would like a definitive solution for this situation.

Comment: I suspect the `calendar.load()` method may be expecting to be passed the contents of `classes/create_cal.php` passed back via the `html` variable (in the success), rather than the file path itself? `var datastring = {date:date};` probably also wants to be `var datastring = {"date":date};` to ensure the first "date" stays as the string date rather than turning in to the datepicker result

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the input. Do you know of a different approach to this, though?